# Eloquent ORM Polymorphic relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to build a role-based user management but segmented by resource of many types.

I have this relational model:
[image: Relational model with basic tables]

I need to show in the user profile management view something like this:
[image: Expected result view]

But I don't want to make queries like:

```
RoleUser::where('user_id',1)->get();
```

I would like to use the **many-to-many polymorphic relationship** to take advantage of the Eager/Lazy loading of Laravel, but I don't know to do it. 
An other interesting feature to take into account, is that I don't want to store in the database the types like `App\Models\Event`, `App\Models\Article` or `App\Models\Photo` but the map is not working well for me (because the relationships aren't set properly).

```
//AppServiceProvider::boot()
Relation::morphMap([
    'event' => Event::class,
    'race'  => Race::class,
]);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    //AppServiceProvider::boot()
    Relation::morphMap([
        'event' => App\Models\Event::class,
        'race'  => App\Models\Race::class,
    ]);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I've done! And it works! Then you can get the 'morphClass' from each model:
 `$event->getMorphClass();` => 'event'